# Server won't recognise get request from client in REST service

Tags: javascript, java, html

(Apologies in advance if I mess up the formatting of the question, this is my first Stackoverflow post.)
I'm trying to make my client send a request to the server for the information of a person with a specific ID. The client sends a GET request to http://localhost:8080/helloWorld/rest/login/{ID}. It does send it as far as I can see, but the first time the server sends back a 500 error and after that every time a 404 error.

I've already checked whether the url is correct, whether I make and send the request correctly, whether my Java program directs the request to the proper method and whether the method properly sends information back, and everything should be working correctly. I've also had several others check over my code and no one saw any problem.
This is the code I have for the JavaScript function and the Java method, respectively:

```
function loginPerson() {

    var fullId = document.getElementById("idInput").value;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/helloWorld/rest/login/" + fullId, true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            console.log(this.statusText);
            setPerson(this.statusText);
            window.location.href = "index.jsp";
        }
    };
    xhttp.send();
    console.log("request sent to http://localhost:8080/helloWorld/rest/login/" + fullId);
}
```

```
@Path("/login")
public class LoginResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person getPersonalInfo(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        return new Person(id);
    }
}
```

The JavaScript function gets called when I press a certain button, and the id is properly retrieved from an input field with id idInput. I also get an error in my Tomcat Localhost Log the first time a request is sent, but it doesn't specify what error. If it matters any, the Person constructor retrieves the information from a database using the id and the Person class is properly specified as an XmlRootElement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem. Apparently I was just missing the following dependency in my pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>
```